# Errors with Tensorflow Cmake Build

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, windows-7, msbuild

I'm trying to build Tensorflow on Windows 7 x64 using the guide published [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md), however, when invoking MSBuild to build TensorFlow (step 4), I get a "Build FAILED" message followed by several errors.

The first:

```
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : CMake can not determine linker language for target: grpc [grpc.vcxproj]
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : CMake can not determine linker language for target: grpc_unsecure [grpc.vcxproj]
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : CMake can not determine linker language for target: cares [grpc.vcxproj]
```

does not make sense because within my grpc CMakelists.txt I have the following defined:

```
set(PACKAGE_NAME      "grpc")
project(${PACKAGE_NAME} C CXX)
```

The other errors all involve source directories not containing a CMakelists.txt file:

```
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : The source directory "C:/tf-dev/local_repos/cub-1.6.4" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. [cub.vcxproj]
```

which occurs for the following external projects:

```
cub
farmhash
fft2d
gemmlowp
gif
highwayhash
jpeg
lmdb
```

However, the Tensorflow build guide does not make any reference to creating additional CMakelists.txt for the externally added projects.  Any idea where I might be going wrong?  Thanks.